# How to optimize an database suggestion engine

Tags: algorithm, optimization, autosuggest, collaborative-filtering

I`m making an online engine for item-to-item recommending movies. I have made some researches and I think that the best way to implement that is using **pearson correlation** and make a table with item1, item2 and correlation fields, but the problem is that after each rate of item I have to regenerate the correlation for in the worst case N records (where N is the number of items).

Another think that I read is the [following](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~zha/CSE8801/CF/p657-onuma.pdf) article, but I haven`t thought a way to implement it.

So what is your suggestion to optimize this process? Or any other suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current approach to this kind of "shopping cart" problems is to use Singular Value Decomposition (SVD). The top-3 participants in the NetFlix Prize all used SVD. SVD is used to perform "dimensionality reduction" on the huge products*persons covariance matrix. The good news is that incremental methods (adding a few observations to the dataset does not imply recomputing the entire matrix) exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no optimal solution but you can find lots of suggestions by looking at "collaborative-filtering" tags or "recommendation-engine" tags on Stack Overflow.